# Memcache in PHP

Tags: php, azure, memcached

I'm setting up a wordpress site on Azure. Wordpress supports Memcache through certain plugins, but I'm not sure if Azure support memcache with PHP? I only found this [article](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) about it, which is on .NET
  If Azure doesn't support memcache with PHP, does it support other types of cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly looks like Azure supports its (never tried it my self, not a PHP person), check out this blog post 
[PHP, Memcache, and Windows Azure Caching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/07/03/php-memcache-and-windows-azure-caching.aspx) from Brian Swan.

*Note Azure Cache supports the Memcache protocol now.

HTH

Comment: Well, I'll definitely try that out. Although interestingly enough, in the phpinfo, I don't see memcache. There is a wincache using opcode, though.